# Save and Show the high score on the screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have an integer high score. But I don't know how save the best of it and show on the screen.

This is my code, thank for your help.

```
-(void)aggiungiPunti
{
    punteggio = punteggio +0001;
    [labelPunteggio setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", punteggio]];
}
```

And in the init method:

```
labelPunteggio = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0000" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:13];
labelPunteggio.position = ccp(30, altezzaSchermo -15);       
[self addChild:labelPunteggio];
```

Comment: is punteggio = punteggio +0001; is your score?

Comment: what about `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: Yes it is the function for add the score.

Comment: I don't know how use NSUserDefaults...

Comment: Can someone give a code for save the high score?

Answer (score 0):

U can do this : 
write this code in app delegate: 
`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"key"]`

In the class where the top score is to be displayed :

```
if([punteggio intValue]>[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"key"]intValue])
{
  //display the score in the desired label
  [labelPunteggio setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", punteggio]];
  // set the new best score in the userDefault
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[punteggio intValue] forKey:@"key"];
}
```

Comment: Thank u! But xcode give me errors in this way.
I explain better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298538/save-the-high-score-cocos2d