# Save the high score cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I try to explain better the situation.

The variables are:

```
int punteggio;

CCLabelTTF *labelPunteggio;
```

Then in the init metod i print my score on the screen:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {

    // PUNTEGGIO
    labelPunteggio = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0000" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:13];

    [self addChild:labelPunteggio];
    ....
    }
}
```

And this is the function to add score on Punteggio: for example, every time i kill a monster i add 10 point.

```
-(void)aggiungiPunti
{
    punteggio = punteggio +0001;

    [labelPunteggio setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", punteggio]];
}
```

But now, i don't know how save the score when the player do game over.
I'd want save this score, and then print the high score on the screen,
i think about

```
-(void) setScore:(int)score
{
    punteggio = highScore;

    if (punteggio>highScore)
    {
        highScore = punteggio;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use NSUserdefaults

```
// Snippet used to save your highscore in the prefs.
int highScore  = yourGameScore;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

//In Game Over screen

```
// Get your highscore from the prefs.
highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HighScore"] intValue ];
```

Comment: The error is: Expected "]" on the line [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: for me it is not showing any error. make sure u added #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> and its and file extension .m or .mm

Answer (score 0):

look at this [link](http://britneyleejohnson.com/?p=238#more-238) and you can use [SettingManager](http://getsetgames.com/2009/10/07/saving-and-loading-user-data-and-preferences/) class to do this work for you. i have used settingManager class for storing highscore. 
Hope this will help